# occasional gazebo crash while spawning models

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running a multi robot setup in simulation. Most of the times gazebo runs fine, but occasionally it will crash out (about 1 in 3 times). The relevant output of the launch script looks like this:

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Msg Waiting for master[ INFO] [1346872005.741139817]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
gzserver: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = gazebo::transport::Publisher]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Service call failed: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
Service call failed: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
Aborted (core dumped)
[ens32_world-2] process has died [pid 6080, exit code 134, cmd optirun /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo /home/piyushk/ros/experimental/stacks/bwi/bwi_gazebo/worlds/ens32.world __name:=ens32_world __log:=/home/piyushk/.ros/log/ce555632-f78c-11e1-888f-848f69a9524e/ens32_world-2.log].
log file: /home/piyushk/.ros/log/ce555632-f78c-11e1-888f-848f69a9524e/ens32_world-2*.log
[person1/spawn_robot-23] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/piyushk/.ros/log/ce555632-f78c-11e1-888f-848f69a9524e/person1-spawn_robot-23*.log
[segbot1/spawn_robot-6] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/piyushk/.ros/log/ce555632-f78c-11e1-888f-848f69a9524e/segbot1-spawn_robot-6*.log
Error [Transport.cc:102] Unable to get topic namespaces in [50] tries.
Error [Node.cc:68] No namespace found
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui: line 2:  6892 Aborted                 (core dumped) `rospack find gazebo`/gazebo/bin/gzclient -g `rospack find gazebo`/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so
[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 6082, exit code 134, cmd optirun /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/piyushk/.ros/log/ce555632-f78c-11e1-888f-848f69a9524e/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/piyushk/.ros/log/ce555632-f78c-11e1-888f-848f69a9524e/gazebo_gui-3*.log
^C[segbot2/move_base-22] killing on exit
[segbot2/fake_localization-21] killing on exit
[segbot2/map_tf_provider-20] killing on exit
[segbot2/kinect_laser_narrow-19] killing on exit
[segbot2/kinect_laser-18] killing on exit
 [segbot2/pointcloud_throttle-17] killing on exit
[segbot2/openni_manager-16] killing on exit
[segbot2/spawn_robot-15] killing on exit
[segbot2/robot_state_publisher-14] killing on exit
[segbot1/move_base-13] killing on exit
[segbot1/fake_localization-12] killing on exit
[segbot1/map_tf_provider-11] killing on exit
[segbot1/kinect_laser_narrow-10] killing on exit
[segbot1/kinect_laser-9] killing on exit
[segbot1/pointcloud_throttle-8] killing on exit
[segbot1/openni_manager-7] killing on exit
[segbot1/robot_state_publisher-5] killing on exit
[bwi_map_server-4] killing on exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/piyushk/ros/experimental/stacks/bwi/bwi_apps/scripts/bwi_map_server", line 216, in <module>
    MapServer()
  File "/home/piyushk/ros/experimental/stacks/bwi/bwi_apps/scripts/bwi_map_server", line 151, in __init__
    rate.sleep();
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/timer.py", line 78, in sleep
    sleep(self.sleep_dur - elapsed)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/timer.py", line 133, in sleep
    raise rospy.exceptions.ROSInterruptException("ROS shutdown request")
rospy.exceptions.ROSInterruptException: ROS shutdown request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/spawn_model", line 277, in <module>
    sm.callSpawnService()
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/spawn_model", line 246, in callSpawnService
    success = gazebo_interface.spawn_urdf_model_client(self.model_name, model_xml, self.robot_namespace, initial_pose, self.reference_frame, self.gazebo_namespace)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/src/gazebo/gazebo_interface.py", line 28, in spawn_urdf_model_client
    rospy.wait_for_service(gazebo_namespace+'/spawn_urdf_model')
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 158, in wait_for_service
    raise ROSInterruptException("rospy shutdown")
rospy.exceptions.ROSInterruptException: rospy shutdown
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

The gazebo log file does not exist. Additionally the log files of the three spawn scripts are below:

person1-spawn_robot-23.log

```
[rospy.client][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,932: init_node, name[/person1/spawn_robot], pid[6696]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,932: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,932: Started XML-RPC server [http://piyushk-laptop:42536/]
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,932: _ready: http://piyushk-laptop:42536/
[rospy.init][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,933: ROS Slave URI: [http://piyushk-laptop:42536/]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,933: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[rospy.registration][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,933: Registering with master node http://localhost:11311
[rospy.init][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:37,033: registered with master
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:37,034: initializing /rosout core topic
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:37,036: connected to core topic /rosout
[rospy.simtime][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:37,037: initializing /clock core topic
[rospy.simtime][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:37,038: connected to core topic /clock
[rosout][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:37,039: waiting for service /ens32_world/spawn_urdf_model
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:37,332: topic[/rosout] adding connection to [/rosout], count 0
[rospy.core][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:46,559: signal_shutdown [atexit]
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:46,566: topic[/rosout] removing connection to /rosout
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:46,566: atexit
```

segbot1-spawn_robot-6.log:

```
[rospy.client][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,019: init_node, name[/segbot1/spawn_robot], pid[6106]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,019: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,019: Started XML-RPC server [http://piyushk-laptop:42289/]
[rospy.init][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,019: ROS Slave URI: [http://piyushk-laptop:42289/]
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,019: _ready: http://piyushk-laptop:42289/
[rospy.registration][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,020: Registering with master node http://localhost:11311
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,020: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[rospy.init][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,120: registered with master
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,120: initializing /rosout core topic
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,123: connected to core topic /rosout
[rospy.simtime][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,124: initializing /clock core topic
[rospy.simtime][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,126: connected to core topic /clock
[rosout][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,130: waiting for service /ens32_world/spawn_urdf_model
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,317: topic[/rosout] adding connection to [/rosout], count 0
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:46,406: topic[/clock] adding connection to [http://piyushk-laptop:33181/], count 0
[rospy.internal][WARNING] 2012-09-05 14:06:46,560: Unknown error initiating TCP/IP socket to piyushk-laptop:58661 (http://piyushk-laptop:33181/): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 511, in connect
    self.socket.connect((dest_addr, dest_port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

[rospy.core][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:46,560: signal_shutdown [atexit]
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:46,569: topic[/rosout] removing connection to /rosout
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:46,569: atexit
```

segbot2-spawn_robot-15.log:

```
[rospy.client][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,570: init_node, name[/segbot2/spawn_robot], pid[6382]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,570: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,571: Started XML-RPC server [http://piyushk-laptop:39168/]
[rospy.init][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,571: ROS Slave URI: [http://piyushk-laptop:39168/]
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,571: _ready: http://piyushk-laptop:39168/
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,571: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[rospy.registration][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,572: Registering with master node http://localhost:11311
[rospy.init][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,671: registered with master
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,672: initializing /rosout core topic
[rospy.rosout][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,675: connected to core topic /rosout
[rospy.simtime][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,676: initializing /clock core topic
[rospy.simtime][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,677: connected to core topic /clock
[rosout][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,681: waiting for service /ens32_world/spawn_urdf_model
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:36,931: topic[/rosout] adding connection to [/rosout], count 0
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:06:46,404: topic[/clock] adding connection to [unknown], count 0
[rospy.internal][WARNING] 2012-09-05 14:06:46,561: Unknown error initiating TCP/IP socket to piyushk-laptop:58661 (http://piyushk-laptop:33181/): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_base.py", line 511, in connect
    self.socket.connect((dest_addr, dest_port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

[rospy.core][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:07:23,378: signal_shutdown [signal-2]
[rospy.internal][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:07:23,389: topic[/rosout] removing connection to /rosout
[rospy.impl.masterslave][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:07:23,390: signal-2
[rospy.core][INFO] 2012-09-05 14:07:24,039: signal_shutdown [atexit]
```

Update #1

[Here](http://zweb.cs.utexas.edu/users/piyushk/share/gazebo_gdb_out_2) is the output with gdb for this error.

[Here](http://zweb.cs.utexas.edu/users/piyushk/share/gazebo_gdb_out) is another error that was produced while running gdb, though I don't remember seeing it before. I was unable to reproduce it after this run.

Update #2

[Output](http://zweb.cs.utexas.edu/users/piyushk/share/gazebo_gdb_out_4) after changing GZ_REGISTER_SYSTEM_PLUGIN. The gazebo trunk was locally downloaded for this run (r40064)

Update #3

[Output](http://zweb.cs.utexas.edu/users/piyushk/share/gazebo_gdb_out_5) Debug set for ROS_BUILD_TYPE.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43112/occasional-gazebo-crash-while-spawning-models/) by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2871 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-09-06**:
one way to begin the debugging process is to start gazebo with gdb attached (i.e. roslaunch gazebo_worlds debug.launch) and look at the backtrace of gzserver when it segfaults.

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-09-06**:
@hsu: see end of updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Piyushk,
thanks for the backtraces, can you put the `GZ_REGISTER_SYSTEM_PLUGIN` macro directly into `gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp`?  i.e. at the end of the file, replace:

```
// Register this plugin with the simulator
GZ_REGISTER_SYSTEM_PLUGIN(GazeboRosApiPlugin)
}
```

with

```
extern "C" gazebo::SystemPlugin *RegisterPlugin();
gazebo::SystemPlugin *RegisterPlugin()
{
  return new GazeboRosApiPlugin();
}
```

and see if the bt gives us some more detail?

thanks,
John

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-09-06**:
John, I have updated the question. I cannot spot a difference. the simulator_gazebo trunk was used instead of simulator_gazebo-1.6.14 deb

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-09-06**:
thanks. what on line /home/piyushk/ros/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/src/gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp:1948?

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2012-09-06**:
I now see what you are driving at. Unfortunately, it was the same line as before (i.e. namespace closing brace). I recompiled gazebo with ROS_BUILD_TYPE set as Debug, and I believe more info is now available. I have updated the question with the gdb output.